# Is it possible to use S/MIME in the web client of Gmail?

Tags: encryption, email

I could not find any options in the web interface of Gmail.

All I could find was a Firefox plugin to use S/MIME with Gmail, but it seems to be outdated.

Comment: related: www.mailvelope.com  you can use PGP in ANY web-application with that plugin

Comment: As per https://blog.google/products/g-suite/advanced-controls-for-gsuite/, this should now be possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is Penango - https://www.penango.com/products - which seems to have a free edition for GMail. I looked into it a while back, since as you say, there isn't anything all that up-to-date, but haven't tried it (ended up going with S/MIME in Outlook checking my GMail account).

Comment: thanks, that works. Be sure, you use the old standard-compose-message function and you import the root PEM certificate into firefox, if you use cacert at https://www.cacert.org/index.php?id=3

Comment: Now it's only the question, how to read those mails on my android phone too? I guess with k9 mail or so...

Comment: Funny enough, my Chrome doesn't trust their SSL certificate.

Comment: Same here, Penagos SSL cert is-- bad

Answer (score 3):

Another option is [Fossa Guard](https://fossa.me) - S/MIME extension for Google Chrome browser. S/MIME certificates are free. And it is interoperable with many other mail clients.

Answer (score 2):

Use R2Mail2 on Android to read, decrypt, verify, sign and encrypt emails of both PGP, PGP/MIME and S/MIME formats. You can use the IMAP+SMTP interface to Gmail.